# compiling c and running code via keybinding

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

I want to compile and run my c code via key binding

```
    gnome-terminal -e make ~/Graphics && /home/johnr/Graphics/se
```

so i add that to `command one` and get the global key `<Alt>r` as the shortcut.
se is the output of compiling.
I have a working Makefile and if i regularly type in the terminal the command inside an actual terminal it work, but when i run it via key binding it pops up a terminal and disappears.

I am setting up my key-binding with gconfig-editor

Any suggestions?